# If the Postgresql pgadmin.exe theme interface gets corrupted

Tags: postgresql, interface, themes, pgadmin

This bug in the screen looks like this:
[image: postgresql pgadmin.exe theme bug]

Comment: Sorry - I'm not sure about what you want to achieve, but I'm assuming you are seeing things different from what you're used to. If you could highlight what you are most concerned about, that would improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

I did a lot of research to solve this problem. but I couldn't find a solution on the internet. Everything seemed normal in the program settings as well. ctrl-scroll etc. as in browsers. I tried combinations but none of them worked. I was able to fix it by doing:

1. run pgadmin.exe
2. file -> preferences -> miscellaneous -> themes -> theme
3. When you look at it, you will see that it says standard.
4. change the theme to dark. and save it.
5. rechange the theme to standard. and save it.
6. it will be fixed. :)
   [image: postgresql pgadmin.exe theme fixed]